# Disable icons using if else conditions

Tags: jquery

In my table I have added two icons for `edit and cancel actions`,In which I am trying to achieve these conditions: If status will be,
`pending`- can perform both approve and reject
`approved`- can perform only cancel
`rejected,cancelled`- should not allow to perform both actions.
But `cancel` is disabling for `Approved` also .What I did wrong?

```
function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
      if (leaveList[i].Status == "Approved") {
                        $(".editAction").attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else if (leaveList[i].Status == "Rejected" || "Cancelled"){
                    $(".editAction,.cancelAction").attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".editAction,.cancelAction").attr('disabled', false);
                    }

         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><td><i class="btn editLev fa fa-calendar-plus-o editAction" onclick="editLevDetails(this)" ></i><i class="btn dltLev fa fa-times cancelAction"  onclick="cancelLeave(this)" data-dismiss="modal"  value="Cancelled" id="' + leaveList[i].LeaveTypeId + '"></i></td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```

check here:https://jsfiddle.net/tytzuckz/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution here:

#### https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5h1ybdp1/2/

there are few bugs in your code:

#### bug 1

`leaveList[i].Status` should be `leaveList[i].status` notice the lower case `s`?

#### bug 2

`leaveList[i].status == "Rejected" || "Cancelled"` will not work, you need to do like this:
`else if (leaveList[i].status == "Rejected" || leaveList[i].status == "Cancelled")`

#### bug 3

`$(".editAction")` will target all class called `editAction` and do action to it, but it is only going to target the one you already created, not you are about to create.

example: here I only fixed your else if to `else if (thisStatus == "Rejected" || thisStatus == "Cancelled")`, as you can see nothing is disabled, why? `Because your last for loop status are = pending` and hit the else condition and called this  `$(".editAction,.cancelAction").attr('disabled', false);` to enable all.
https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/tytzuckz/27/

#### what id did here:

I added `editDis` and `cancelDis` as disable indicator by default it is `''` so not going to disable anything, using the following if to check if any of the button should be disabled then I update them for example  `editDis = ' disabled '` then at the end I put those into edit button tag and cancel button tag, if the value for `editDis` is `''` it is not going to disable the button, otherwise it will have `disabled` therefore disabled that button.

```
function leaveTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
    var editDis = '';
    var cancelDis = '';
    var thisStatus = leaveList[i].status;
    if (thisStatus == "Approved") {
      console.log('what>');
      editDis = ' disabled ';
    } else if (thisStatus == "Rejected" || thisStatus == "Cancelled") {
      editDis = ' disabled ';
      cancelDis = ' disabled ';
    }

    var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><td><i class="btn editLev fa fa-calendar-plus-o editAction" onclick="editLevDetails(this)" ' + editDis + '></i><i class="btn dltLev fa fa-times cancelAction"  ' + cancelDis + ' onclick="cancelLeave(this)" data-dismiss="modal"  value="Cancelled" id="' + leaveList[i].LeaveTypeId + '"></i></td><tr>';

    $('#levListTable').append(tab)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why we need this `var editDis = '';` `var cancelDis = '';`

Comment: @user7397787 ok, inside your `var tab` I have `editDis` in edit button tag and `cancelDis` in cancel button tag, by default they are empty string so they are not going to do anything, if the edit button should be disabled, you set `editDis` to `'disabled'` then after you append the row, that edit button have an attribute `disabled`, instead of using jQuery to target because jQuery can't target the button if they are not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and tell me if it work.

```
function leaveTable() {
     for (var i = 0; i < leaveList.length; i++) {
      if (leaveList[i].Status == "Approved") {
                        $(".editAction").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(".cancelAction").removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                    else if (leaveList[i].Status == "Rejected" || "Cancelled"){
                    $(".editAction,.cancelAction").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".editAction,.cancelAction").removeAttr('disabled');
                    }

         var tab = '<tr id="' + i + '"><td>' + (i + 1) + '</td><td class="appliedOn">' + leaveList[i].appliedOn + '</td><td class="levType" >' + leaveList[i].levType + '</td><td class="leaveOn" >' + leaveList[i].leaveOn + '</td><td class="duration">' + leaveList[i].duration + '</td><td class="status">' + leaveList[i].status + '</td><td class="approvedOn">' + leaveList[i].approvedOn + '</td><td class="approvedBy">' + leaveList[i].approvedBy + '</td><td><i class="btn editLev fa fa-calendar-plus-o editAction" onclick="editLevDetails(this)" ></i><i class="btn dltLev fa fa-times cancelAction"  onclick="cancelLeave(this)" data-dismiss="modal"  value="Cancelled" id="' + leaveList[i].LeaveTypeId + '"></i></td><tr>';

         $('#levListTable').append(tab)
     }
 }
```